# Solution for Turkish-I in C++

Tags: c++, string-comparison

**Hi all!**

In Turkish one of the letters of alphabet has a different behaviour, it's I -and i-. In English I and i are upper & lower cases. In Turkish lowercase of I is not i, instead **ı**.

So in Turkish environment (ie Windows) "DOMAIN.COM" and "domain.com" are not equal. Since email transport & DNS are completely in English, if mail addresses contain uppercase I, there might be a problem.

In C# we may use **InvariantCultureIgnoreCase** flag to correct the issue:

```
        // Mock
        string localDomain = "domain.com";
        string mailAddress = "USER@DOMAIN.COM";
        string domainOfAddress = mailAddress.Split('@')[1];
        string localInbox = "";

        //
        // Local inbox check

        //Case insensitive method 
        bool ignoreCase = true; // Equal to StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
        if (System.String.Compare(localDomain, domainOfAddress, ignoreCase) == 0) 
        { 
           // This one fails in Turkish environment
           localInbox = mailAddress.Split('@')[0];
        }


        //Culture-safe version
        if (System.String.Compare(localDomain, domainOfAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            // This one is the correct/universal method
            localInbox = mailAddress.Split('@')[0];
        }
```

Since I'm not experienced at C++ what would be the **C++ equivalents** of these two examples?

Comment: When you talk about C++, which variant do you mean? I ask as you can write applications for .NET in C++, so the equivalent would be virtually the same, excusing any syntax differences.

Comment: Microsoft VC version would be nice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are programming in `Windows`, you may change `locale` of your thread to `en_US` and then use `_stricmp`, or create a locale object for `en_US` and then use `_stricmp_l`:

```
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "English" );
assert( _stricmp("DOMAIN", "domain") == 0 );

_locale_t l = _create_locale( LC_CTYPE, "English" );
assert( _stricmp_l("DOMAIN", "domain", l) == 0 );
```

If `boost` is an option for you, a more portable and C++ friendly solution is to use [boost::locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) library

Comment: The `_locale_t` structure should be freed using `_free_locale` when it is no longer needed according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zx9aht2.aspx).